# Pointers and references + overloaded operators

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

Let's say I have a program in which I want to solve equations(something like this)

```
Number x;
Func fw = x * 4 + x * x;
std::cout << fw(6.0) << "\n\n";
```

Thus, I'm starting from writing abstract Base class, where I have all what I need to solve this equation.

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base(){};
    virtual Base* operator*(Base& x) = 0;
    virtual Base* operator*(double x) = 0;
    virtual Base* operator+(Base& x) = 0;
};
```

and class Number

```
class Number : public Base
{
public:
    virtual Base* operator*(Base& x);
    virtual Base* operator*(double x);
    virtual Base* operator+(Base& x);
};
```

and class Func with copy constructor(or at least, Ithink that it's a copy constructor)

```
class Func: public Base
{
    Base * func;
public:
    Func(Base* other)
    {
        func = other;
    }

    Func(Base& other)
    {
        func = &other;
    }

    virtual Base* operator*(Base& x){}

    virtual Base* operator*(double x){}

    virtual Base* operator+(Base&){}

};
```

So, my problem. My program works for `x*x` or for `x*4`, but when I try to combine them `x*x + x*4` I have a problem.

It's obvious(or it is not) what the problem is.After `x*x` my program is returning pointer(Base*) and in my overloaded operators I have only (Base&).
So program can't match any overloaded operator to it.

Here is what CLion shows me `binary operator + can't be applied to the expression of type Base* and Base*`

So, solution can be to overload operators one more time but with argument(Base*), but I hope there is a better way to solve this problem. Is there?

Comment: Basic data types don't supporting adding float and int together directly, for example. Instead there is a promotion, int to float in this case. Perhaps you can solve the problem in a similar way. Promote your different types to the same type and then perform the operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is: write a wrapper class that uses value or reference semantics rather than pointer semantics. For example,

```
class BaseRep // I've renamed your `Base` class
{
public:
    BaseRep(){};
    virtual std::unique_ptr<BaseRep> multiply(const BaseRep& x) = 0;
};

class Base
{
    std::unique_ptr<BaseRep> ptr;
public:
    Base(std::unique_ptr<BaseRep> &&p):ptr(p) {}
    BaseRep& rep() { return *ptr; }
    const BaseRep& rep() const { return *ptr; }
    // and other stuff
};

Base operator*(const Base &x, const Base &y)
{
    return Base( x.rep().multiply(y.rep()) );
}
```

Comment: Don't you need a virtual destructor?

Comment: @Neil: Yes; this example was not meant to be a complete library, just a demonstration of the essentials of the idea. (also, I blame the fact I copy-paste-edited from the OP's post)

Answer (score 0):

all arithmetic operators should return a reference (or a copy), absolutely not a pointer.

Comment: Returning by copy slices; returning by reference leaks (or dangles). The real answer is "this design is completely broken".

Comment: @T.C.  I agree with you. However, I have to write this program like that :C

Comment: easy to fix. the polymorphic concept should be owned by a non-polymorphic handle class. Then add a clone method to the polymorphic concept and implement copies in terms of that. Then of course you'll need some means of resolving the dynamic dispatch when two dissimilar objects are added.... or you could use `boost::variant`.

Answer (score 0):

```
template < size_t Index >
struct placeholder {
    template < typename ... Args >
    auto operator()(Args ... args) const
    {
        auto tpl = std::make_tuple(args...);
        return get<Index>(tpl);
    }

 };

 placeholder<0> _1;
 placeholder<1> _2; // etc...

 template < typename T >
 struct val
 {
    T value;
    val(T v) : value(v) {}

    template < typename ... Args >
    auto operator()(Args ... ) const { return value; }
 };

 template < typename LH, typename RH >
 struct plus_operator
 {
     plus_operator(LH l, RH r) : lh(l), rh(r) {}

     LH lh;
     RH rh;

    template < typename ... Args >
    auto operator()(Args ... args) const { return lh(args...) + rh(args...); }
 };

 template < size_t I, typename T >
 auto operator + (placeholder<I> lh, T rh)
 {
     return plus_operator<placeholder<I>,T>{lh,val<T>{rh}};
 }
 template < typename T, size_t I >
 auto operator + (T lh, placeholder<I> rh) ...
 // because this would otherwise be ambiguous...
 template < size_t I1, size_t I2 >
 auto operator + (placeholder<I1> lh, placeholder<I2> rh) ...
```

Same same for *, -, /...

```
 auto fun = _1 * 4 + _1 * _1;

 auto result = fun(5);
```

Not tested.  No warranty.  But this technique is I believe what you want to solve the problem.  It's called 'expression templates'.

Oh, and you'll have to override for each possible operator being LH, RH...probably a better way using SFINAE.